# How to feature flag/toggle TypeScript service/class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, featuretoggle, feature-flags

I would like to feature flag a service in my React app so I can toggle it on and off by changing a boolean in a config file. However, I am unsure as to how best to do so. The service is as below:

```
class Service {
  constructor() {
    // do stuff
  }

  doA() {
    // do stuff
  }

  doB() {
    // do stuff
  }

  // more methods
}

export const serviceInstance = new Service();
```

This service's methods are called in different parts of the application.

Currently, I am flagging it by creating another class with the same methods and attributes as `Service` and then exporting the relevant instance based on the feature flag boolean:

```
class ServiceMock {
  constructor() {
    return;
  }

  doA() {
    return;
  }

  doB() {
    return;
  }

  // more empty return methods
}

export const serviceInstance = serviceFlag ? new Service() : new ServiceMock();
```

It works but I am worried that this is rather inefficient, especially when the number of methods and attributes grow. Is there a better way to feature flag something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to TypeScript, but does this help any?

```
interface IService {
    doA(): void
    doB(): void
}

class Service implements IService {
    doA(): void {
        console.log("doA");
    }
    doB(): void {
        console.log("doB");
    }
}

class ServiceMock implements IService {
    doA(): void {
        console.log("mockA");
    }
    doB(): void {
        console.log("mockB");
    }
}

function createService(serviceFlag: boolean): IService {
    return (serviceFlag) ? new Service() : new ServiceMock();
}

const originalServiceInstance = createService(true);
const mockServiceInstance = createService(false);
originalServiceInstance.doA();
mockServiceInstance.doA();
```

If anyone has improvements or suggestions, I'm still struggling with coming to TypeScript from python and would be happy to improve this answer.

It runs without error at [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGVoDdhOQbwCgBIAEwHsBBACgEoAuZLc4Uw5D5CgITsedaEAvoUIIANnADOU5Jig48wALYAHcRGURwsjNlwoinLlT5MWpAu2OcE5EFPIaAdOPIBzagCIKlL7QBuaw4RYx4zAUsjGw47BycIVw9vHn8g4xERMUkZOX0kAFlyBABrZBV1TW0wXXlFQ2CTGgZzVisY2PtHFzdPL2Vikr9AxtDOcJbI9o647sTe7wHS7jTR4VEYAFcQBDBge2QEKAg4SDqDail8iAAxSXdGACNyBLgQFr0FAytiY7BNqAgZCXa53ODuWjIAD8yBAEAA7nkvkg6MhGHDEedCoM6EEsrMwMhyFBgO5QHBxFiIKgHGA3ngALyHY6nCBU6hgKCbCAjAnIJYlKk0qR0nYoJlHE5na7UeDiK4jYmk8mU67C0VIZy+XGEAVC2n0xLakZAA).

Answer (score 0):

You should have used webpack in your project. The best way is just to build what code you need. But in your demo code `export const serviceInstance = serviceFlag ? new Service() : new ServiceMock();`, It'll build all the two services into your runtime code.

It would help if you did this config in webpack.

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.serviceFlag': JSON.stringify(process.env.serviceFlag),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Then to use the environment variable in your code like so `export const serviceInstance = process.env.serviceFlag === "true" ? new Service() : new ServiceMock();`.
Finally don't forget to pass the environment variable in the npm script.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env serviceFlag=true umi build",
    "build:mock": "cross-env serviceFlag=false umi build",
  },
}
```

Now you can `npm run build` or `npm run build:mock`, the runtime code just includes one of the service.